# The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port in BizTalk Server 2009

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2009, send-port

I am using BizTalk Server 2009 to send EDI messages to my client using AS2. I am able to send messages, but getting an error while sending messages that exceeds 5KB of file size. I checked with the partner whether they are using any restrictions on file size, but they are able to exchange even some GB's of files with other trading partner.

I compared the files that are successfully sent with the one that failed. But found no difference between two except LIN, PIA, QTY and other segments.

I found the below error when tracked in event viewer.

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SendTextFile" with URL "http://xxclienturlxx.com:2080/ipnet/as2". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.".

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution..

In BizTalk 2009, disabling "Enable chunked encoding" in Send port Transport type properties did the trick for me...

> To have large message support when the size of the message is greater than 48 KB, the http send adapter is sending the data in chunks to the server instead of a full stream"

This post [HTTP Send Adapter - Submit to ASP Page Issue](http://deepakl.blogspot.in/2005/09/http-send-adapter-submit-to-asp-page.html) helped me to find the solution.